# Is it possible to use newlines in a fold marker?

Tags: folding

I am trying to set `foldmarker={{{,\n\n\n`, so that `{{{` starts a fold and two consecutive empty lines end a fold. However, vim treats this as equivalent to `foldmarker={{{,nnn`. Is it possible to use newlines in a fold marker in this way?

Comment: What if you double escape the backslashes? `\\n` ?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Then it looks for a literal `\n\n\n`

Comment: What about `execute 'set foldmarker={{{,^VEnter'` (use `<C-v>` to type a literal Enter three times)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## fold-marker

The [entry for `foldmarker`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27foldmarker%27) notes that:

> The marker is a literal string (a regular expression would be too slow).

...so you don't have full use of all the usual escapes sequences.

The section [`option-backslash`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#option-backslash) shows that the arguments to "set" can include a backslash to escape whitespace, quotemarks, or backslashes themselves.  But it doesn't appear to be possible to escape a newline this way (because that still ends the "set" command).

## fold-syntax

You can instead set multiline fold markers using [syntax folding](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#:syn-fold).

```
syn region myFold start="{{{" end="\n\n\n" transparent fold
syn sync fromstart
set foldmethod=syntax
```